# How to fix this compilation error of pngquant: "fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory'"?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, aws, configure

*(Existing answers do not address this particular situation)*

Currently the error message is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:33:0,
                 from pngquant.c:37:
/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1075/include/linux/stddef.h:4:31: fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory
```

**Full Background**

I am trying to compile [`pngquant`](https://github.com/kornelski/pngquant) from source and I am trying to put the output files to an alternative location.

`pngquant` has a dependency on [`libimagequant`](https://github.com/ImageOptim/libimagequant/). Here is the way I build the code:

```
# Required dependency
apt-get install libpng16-dev

cd libimagequant-2.12.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/alt-location
make and sudo make install
```

Now it is `pngquant`'s turn

```
cd pngquant-2.12.1    
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/alt-location --with-libimagequant=/src/to/libimagequant
```

If I compile it on a ubuntu distribution, it will run to the end and a binary is generated.

```
$ make &&  sudo make install
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
mkdir -p '/usr/local/alt-location/bin'
mkdir -p '/usr/local/alt-location/share/man/man1'
install -m 0755 -p 'pngquant' '/usr/local/alt-location/bin/pngquant'
install -m 0644 -p 'pngquant.1' '/usr/local/alt-location/share/man/man1/'
```

Smoke test:

```
[10:20:13] sde:pngquant-2.12.1$ /usr/local/alt-location/bin/pngquant --version
2.12.0 (January 2018)
```

However if I repeat the same process on an AWS ec2 instance (with xenial) I got this error:

```
$ make
gcc -fno-math-errno -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -std=c99 -I. -O3 -DNDEBUG -DUSE_SSE=1 -msse -mfpmath=sse -Wno-unknown-pragmas -I/usr/local/alt-location/include -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1075/include/linux -fexcess-precision=fast   -c -o pngquant.o pngquant.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:33:0,
                 from pngquant.c:37:
/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1075/include/linux/stddef.h:4:31: fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'pngquant.o' failed
make: *** [pngquant.o] Error 1
```

**My question:**

How can I fix this issue? Does it has anything to do with the fact that this linux version is actually customised by aws?

**Edit**

Trying to install missed header as suggested but it seems the headers are already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.4.0-1081-aws is already the newest version (4.4.0-1081.91).
linux-headers-4.4.0-1081-aws set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=pngquant). What was wrong with simple `sudo apt-get install pngquant`? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 1) The latest version is not available to xenial 2) I want to keep two versions in different location

Comment: OK, I see, then start with getting its dependencies with `sudo apt-get build-dep pngquant` and then retry.

Comment: It failed with `Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: You need to enable `deb-src` repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` first; then run `sudo apt-get update`. And to install [missed header](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=uapi%2Flinux%2Fstddef.h) you can try to install it with `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

Comment: The 'missed header' link in your comment is not working... Also the headers seems to be installed.

Comment: The `--with-libxxx` specification would usually be the **top level** location i.e. the directory containing **both** `include` and `lib` subdirectories -  so `--with-libimagequant=/usr/local/alt-location/`

Comment: I get this error instead: 'imagequant: error ... libimagequant.h not found in /usr/local/media-import'

Comment: @steeldriver It turns `with-libimagequant` should point to the source directory of  `libimagequan`

Answer (score 1):

run
`apt-get install libc6-dev`
which should get you `stddef` lib you're looking for

It's generally good idea to start with:
`sudo apt-get install build-essential` to avoid libraries missing.

additionally, if you have some missing lib you can find packages with them with apt-file:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt update
apt-file search stddef.h
```

and you'll get info which packages provide the file

Comment: No luck: `libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu11).` and `build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).`

Comment: can you please show me result of `dpkg -C clang` and `dpkg -C libclang
` in that case? As far as I remember you should be using `clang` package here for the correct results.

Comment: They are not installed. gcc version is 
`gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: please install clang in that case, and let me know what you get then

Comment: I prefer not to. It is clearly a case of some deviation of aws linux. My other software on the system are compiled with the default `gcc`

Comment: I don' think so and just found this:
https://github.com/bsteinb/rsmpi/issues/1 which also suggests installing clang for 16.04